# JavaFX WebView: HTML loading css/images from resources folder

Tags: javafx, webview

I am using a JavaFX `WebView` to display HTML help:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import java.net.URL;

public final class HelpPane extends BorderPane {

    private static final String HELP_RESOURCE_NAME = "/help/main.html";

    public HelpPane() {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        URL url = HelpPane.class.getResource(HELP_RESOURCE_NAME);
        webEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());

        setCenter(webView);
    }

}
```

The `main.html`, a `style.css` and various images all reside in a `help` folder inside `resources` :

[image]

From `main.html`, I am using relative links to load CSS and images:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Help</h1>

<img src="img/main-vs-side-panels.png" width="600px"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works perfectly fine on OSX (both, when launching from IDE and from a jar). **On Windows, when launching from jar, the CSS and img links are no longer resolved** (launching from IDE works fine).

Is there a better aka more robust way for linking to resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is caused by an actual bug. Everything works fine with the latest JRE 1.8.0_92.